# How to return json using mongoid

Tags: json, ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I have a model:

```
class Client
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :age, type: Integer
  index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true })

  def self.list
    self.all.as_json
  end
end
```

When I call Client.list I get the following:

```
[{"client"=>{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"58e91ccb9509d36cbaa8c79b"}, "name"=>"mark", "age"=>30}}]
```

What I am after is:

```
[{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"58e91ccb9509d36cbaa8c79b"}, "name"=>"mark", "age"=>30}]
```

Comment: I had the same issue so, I have written a blog on how I solved it. you might find it helpful. https://medium.com/aviabird/mongoid-how-to-serialize-to-json-with-a-string-id-attribute-2d5c1bc284a7

Comment: @VoidZero this is not the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of mongoid are you using ?

Check the documentation at:
https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.1.0/mongoid-installation/

You can disable the `include_root_in_json` to remove the model name of the output json.

Can you try this solution?

Comment: Using mongo 2.4.1, Using mongoid 6.1.0, Using bson 4.2.1. Problem is why by default mongoid returns the class name inside the result. That's not what the data looks like inside the DB

Comment: I think I don't understand your point, but you read the link that I sent ? The class name can be disabled in the output of json.